# Are there any philosophical works on the social meta hierarchies created by technology(the emergence of the internet)?

Tags: sociology, philosophy-of-technology, philosophy-of-social-sciences

Since the 1990s many people have been able to interact in ways that were not accessible to them before due to the internet.
Since the online interactions differ in many respects from those in real life and probably also the hierarchies that are formed in many kinds of places in the web. I very interested in works that present some sort of meta hierarchies which classify people in a way that their position in these hierarchies determines their likelihood of being in certain positions in other hierarchies(e.g a hierarchy in a social network).

Comment: I doubt that this is a philosophy question, it sounds like a sociological field study.

Comment: "social meta hierarchies" ??? What are they ?

Comment: @conifold I really thought that sociological constructs are still studied in philosophy.

Comment: The invocation of the phrase 'emergence of the Internet' is likely to be too specific for novel philosophical work. The same metaphysical discussion in [the philosophy of social science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_social_science) would be applicable with or without the specificity related to the Internet. If anything, you might want to consider rephrasing the question as a philosophy of technology question, but the exact ask, which is specific research is an empirical question for social science proper. the ask is an intersection of social science, technology, AND philosophy.